# Bootstrap Removing whitespace between columns in same row after break

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On Bootstrap 3.

If you run the below html and css, the divs render correctly with no space above 768px. As soon as you reach that breakpoint, the divs stack on top of one another, which is perfectly fine. However, there's this mysterious white space that appears between the two divs. If you pop open dev tools, there is no margin or position set of any kind, and setting a negative margin via media query for the second div does not help. I am at a loss at what precisely is causing this white space.

It almost seems like the first div sticks to the top of the nav element and the second sticks to the bottom on the breakpoint, but that is a hunch and I'm not sure how I'd remedy it. Html and CSS are below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 brand">
                <h1>CruisingFree!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 navlinks">
                <p>Some more stuff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
nav {
    height: 100%;
}

.brand {
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3);
}

.navlinks {
    background-color: rgba(59, 128, 173, 0.5);
    height: 69px;
}

.navlinks p {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually the margin of the `<h1>` tag that is extending out of the `col-sm-4` `div`.

[image]

One way to take care of it using Bootstrap would be to identify the point at which breaking occurs and remove margin for the `h1` for that using a media query.
Something like this.

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .brand h1 {
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

[Note : I used `.brand h1` here to refer to the `h1` because then it will only apply to that specific `h1` tag and not all the `h1` tags in the page.]

And voila: 
[image]

See [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsxty0ew/1/).

Comment: Please upvote and mark as the right answer if it helped you. Thanks.